# What is the limit of radius of double integral for a right-shifted circle in polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, limits, polar-coordinates

> Use polar coordinates to evaluate the double integral $\iint_R2ydA$. $R$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded above by $x^2−2x+y^2=0$ and below by the line $y=x$.

I have determined the limit of $\theta$, which is $\pi/4$ by using the equation $r\sin(\theta)=r\cos(\theta)$. But how to find the limit of the radius? Is the radius simply $0$ to $1$? This is a circle with a radius of $1$ unit shifted to the right by $1$ unit after completing the square. Thanks.

Comment: $r$ extends from $0$ to the circle, so you need the equation of the circle in polar coordinates. Also, $\theta$ is from $\pi /4$ to ??

Comment: $x =r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$, so the equation of the circle in polar coordinates is $(r\cos\theta)^2 - 2r\cos\theta + (r\sin\theta)^2 = 0$. Now solve for $r$ in terms of $\theta$.